# How read fragmented media data in iOS

Tags: ios, avassetwriter, nsfilehandle, avassetreader

I have developed an iOS application which can records videos for long durations , i have used `AVCaptureSesssion` to use recording

But now i want to split recorded media data according to timestamp and i  thought of doing this according to following steps

1) Write media data in to a file using `AVAssetWriter` (which is already implemented )
2) Assign `movieFragmentInterval` for recorded data to create fragment atoms for each 5 seconds 
3) Read media data fragments
4) Create a movie file from split media fragments

i went through with following link and i understood that making chunks and read it will be easy ,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473360/is-it-possible-to-do-video-file-chunking-segmenting-while-still-recording-usin](http://how%20to%20make%20chunks%20with%20movieFragmentInterval)

i want to read timestamp data from saved fragment and is there any api to read media fragments  ?? and to create a separate movie from that

Comment: Did you checked the timeRange property, which can get particular frame by time value.

Comment: @Nikhil.T i used FFMPEG to get keyframes and from that i managed to split videos from original media file