# Streaming live video from ios

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I have a need to stream video from the iPhone/iPad camera to a server. It looks like this will need to be done with AVCaptureSession but I don't know how to best architect this.

I found this post:

[streaming video FROM an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444791/streaming-video-from-an-iphone)

But it doesn't handle the "live" part, latency needs to be 2 or 3 seconds at most. Devices can be constrained to 4 or 4S capability if needed, and there is no requirement for HD, VGA is probably what we'll end up with. I assume any solution would use ffmpeg, I haven't found any more appropriate library.

How is this best accomplished?

Comment: hey are you getting any thing, how to do live stream data from iphone to server, if know please share with me, i also want same. Thank you

Comment: ANGL iOS library supports RTMP streaming to a compatible server like Wowza. It has some delay but works quite well. Filtering is also supported.
http://angl.tv/lib/

Answer (score 4):

According to Apple, if you send large amounts of data from an iPhone app you're going to have to use HTTP Live Streaming.

[HTTP Live Streaming Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[It's possible, here's an App that does it called Livu](http://stevemcfarlin.com/livu/index.html)

Try working with [ffmpeg for iPhone](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ffmpeg4iphone/) and the [segmenter](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/) from Carson Macdonald's excellent Ion Cannon site which has a lot of useful information on HTTP Live Streaming. He's a user here too and can offer invaluable advice.

Comment: The question is about sending video FROM an iPhone. The Apple guideline is referring to an application that sends lots of data TO an iPhone over 3G.