# Stream local videos from iOS (not live streaming)

Tags: iphone, webserver

I am looking for some way to host user selected local video in iOS. 
I found one application named "Realtimes" which can stream local videos to Chromecast. I am not sure how they are doing it but this is what i want to do.
Can anybody point me in right direction?

I have already looked into this thread which is specific to live streaming from camera which is not i want:
[Streaming live video from ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841169/streaming-live-video-from-ios)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed a small web server in your app to serve the content that you want to the chromecast; you would then need to send the URL for those content (that would point to your embedded server) to the chromecast and from chromecast's point of view, it is just accessing another content over http. Note that you cannot serve any type of encrypted or adaptive media this way.