# Starting point for video calling for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, video, call

I am not looking for an API for video calling here. I know about some APIs like OpenTok.

But I want to create my own methods to make a video calling app.

How can I start on this? I have good knowledge of JSON and SOAP services and I have done some work on streaming in my past, will that help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's really challenging. First iOS haven't a specific API to stream audio+video through the internet. The main issue here is that with AVFoundation you can capture single frames, but sending them without compression it will be really painfull even for a wifi connection or for the server. To compress a video you can use CPU but this will require intense operations that will drain battery and heat you device. There is way to compress video using a specific chip on iPhone, but it is used only if you write on the device using `AVAssetWriter` class. 
There are some useful question on stack about it such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444791/streaming-video-from-an-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own methods to make a video calling app, a good starting point would be to look at AVFoundation's [Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2).

After that, you'll need to find a way to read and write bytes to and from the devices. You can test this with ad hoc build (TCP server).

Set up a server so it can act like a proxy for the devices to talk to each other.